# How to solve the following errors "Name 'X' is not defined" when Subtracting multiple column data from two CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to subtract multiple column data from two text file. The text file contain 6 columns and these columns are not named.So I named it as No,X,Y,Z,Date,Time and seperated with comma.  I want to perform X-X1, Y-Y1, Z-Z1. Date and Time are not important and they are only for reference.    For this I have opened the files with different dataframe and I have used concat and then I produced another csv file which contains data from two text file in single CSV file. Now when I am subtracting the columns X-X1, Y-Y1, Z-Z1 I am getting the following error: "Name 'X' is not defined" also I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv', when trying to produce file named "difference.csv".
Please help me to solve this error. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\Work\\Data1.txt', names=['No1','X1','Y1','Z1','Date1','Time1'], sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('D:\\Work\\Data19.txt', names=['No','X','Y','Z','Date','Time'], sep='\s+')

total=pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
total.to_csv("merge.csv")
cols = ['X','Y','Z','X1','Y1','Z1']
print(total)

df3 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\project1\\merge.csv')

df4[X,Y,Z] = df3[X,Y,Z]-df3[X1,Y1,Z1]
print(df4)
df4.to_csv("difference.csv")
```

Comment: Change `df4[X,Y,Z] = df3[X,Y,Z]-df3[X1,Y1,Z1]` to `df4 = df3[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] -df3[['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']]`.

Comment: @timus When I am editing my code with above lines I am getting columns with "NaN" as shown below:   

                X   X1       Y      Y1   Z      Z1
      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: Try `df4 = df3[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] - df3[['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']].rename(columns=lambda c: c[0])`. Also make sure that you don't write the index to the file (`total.to_csv("merge.csv", index=False)` - as pointed out in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about fixing your code like this?

`df1 = pd.read_table('D:\\Work\\Data1.txt', names=['No1','X1','Y1','Z1','Date1','Time1'], sep='\s+')`

`df2 = pd.read_table('D:\\Work\\Data19.txt', names=['No','X','Y','Z','Date','Time'], sep='\s+')`

`total.to_csv('merge.zip', index = False)`

Also, I think the index of the data frame resulting from the code below is

`total=pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)`
`['No1','X1','Y1','Z1','Date1','Time1','No','X','Y','Z','Date','Time']`

I hope my answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df3["X2"] = df3["X"]-df3["X1"]
df3["Y2"] = df3["Y"]-df3["Y1"]
df3["Z2"] = df3["Z"]-df3["Z1"]

df4 = df3.loc[:, ["X2", "Y2", "Z2"]
df4 = df4.rename(columns={"X2": "X", "Y2": "Y", "Z2": "Z"}) #optional

df4.to_csv("difference.csv")
```